# How to look up the first row in a DF #1 that matches the values from DF #2?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a very large DF with bike ride data from the Chicago DIVVY system. It includes start/end data for each ride, including station ID and lat/lng information.

My Goal: find the station with the most "start" rides. Return the number of rides and the lat/long data for the station.

I can find the 15 busiest stations with:

```
df['startID'].value_counts().head(15)
```

This creates a pd.series with the ID (as index) and the N rides. Executes quite fast (<1 sec).

(After changing the series to a DF) What's the easiest / fastest way to **add the lat/lng data** to this df?

I've got a very kludgy and slow solution that takes the series, turns it into a DF, and then iterates over the DF, looking up the station ID in the big DF and returns the lat/lng values. (I put these in a dictionary, because I will plot them on a map later.)

```
points = {}
for index, row in stat_df.iterrows():
    id = row['start_station_id']
    lat_lng = bigData.loc[bigData['start_station_id'] == id].head(1)[['start_lat','start_lng']].values.tolist()
    points[id] = [row['count'],lat_lng[0]]
```

Although my list is short (15 stations/rows), this is REALLY slow (over 2 minutes!), since .loc finds all the rows in the main DF that match the station ID (thousands of rows) and then takes just the head row.

I've tried to use .merge() to match the station/frequency table with the big DF, but that does a one-to-many match, which results in a huge new DF, which isn't what I want.

This seems like a very basic goal, so I suspect there is a simple solution that eludes me.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do? Where df1 equal the list of highest starts and df2 is the df that would have all the long/lats?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Location' : ['Here', 'There', 'Over There'],
    'Count' : [1000, 20000, 3000]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Location' : ['Here', 'Here', 'Somewhere', 'There', 'Else where', 'Over There'],
    'Long_Lat' : [10.123, 10.123, 21830.238, 10238.2318, 830.2139, 10223.123]
})

pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates())
```

Comment: Yes, but the DF with all the lat/long data has multiple rows for each station ID. So when I merge on station ID, I get the one row from DF1 matching 10,000+ rows from DF2. So in your df2, it would be 'Location':['Here','Here','Here','There','Here','There'...] So when I merge, I have a one-to-many join, rather than just finding one record in DF2 that matches the Location ID in DF1.

Comment: Is there any reason why `pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates())` would not work?

Comment: Thanks - this worked! And took only 5.2 seconds.

Comment: In the shower, it occurred to me that I could make a table just of the station ID numbers and their lat/long locations, then do merges against that. Using df.drop_duplicates() allowed me to do this in 1.3 seconds. And merging with a 1500 row table will go much faster in the future.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad that it worked for you! If the answer works for you please upvote and mark as answered so others can find the answer with similar questions.